# Networkx, positioning of nodes that are integers, not strings

Tags: python, networkx

my goal is to position two graphs, relative to one another.

I keep sets of nodes, and node labels separately for each graph.

```
n, p, seedd = 5, 0.7, 13
g1 = fast_gnp_random_graph(3, 1, seed = seedd, directed = False)
g2 = fast_gnp_random_graph(n, p, seed = seedd, directed = False)

# making sure nodes are not duplicated for drawing edges later.
dup = 0
for i in g1.nodes:
    if g2.has_node(i):
        dup = dup +1
g2 = relabel_nodes(g2, {i:i+dup for i in g2.nodes})

g1_labels = {i: label for i, label in enumerate(['appel', 'peahc', 'pppuy'])}
g2_labels = {i: label for i, label in zip(g2.nodes, ['ape', 'apple', 'peach', 'puppy', 'rand'])}
set_node_attributes(g1, g1_labels, 'label')
set_node_attributes(g2, g2_labels, 'label')

pos_1 = nx.spring_layout(g1)
pos_2 = nx.spring_layout(g2)

# shift g2 away from g1 for plotting. 
for node in g2:
    pos_2[node][0] += 4

# map nodes across g1 and g2 randomly. 
g2_map = choice(g2.nodes, number_of_nodes(g1), replace = False)
new_bipartite = [[i, j] for i, j in zip(g1.nodes, g2_map)]
B = Graph()
B.add_nodes_from(g1.nodes, bipartite = 0)
B.add_nodes_from(g2.nodes, bipartite = 1)
B.add_edges_from(new_bipartite) 

figure(figsize = (15, 15))
draw_networkx(g1, pos_1, node_color = '#5499c7', node_size = 400, with_labels = False)
draw_networkx(g2, pos_2, node_color = '#d35400', node_size = 400, with_labels = False)

g1_color = ['#5499c7' for node in range(0, number_of_nodes(g1))]
g2_color = ['#d35400' for node in range(0, number_of_nodes(g2))]

draw_networkx(B, pos = dict(pos_1, **pos_2), width = 2, style = 'dashed',  node_color = g1_color + g2_color, node_size = 400, font_size = 28)
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_9792/3082168389.py in <module>
      2 draw_networkx(g1, pos_1, node_color = '#5499c7', node_size = 400, with_labels = False)
      3 draw_networkx(g2, pos_2, node_color = '#d35400', node_size = 400, with_labels = False)
----> 4 draw_networkx(B, pos = dict(pos_1, **pos_2), type = 'dashed')

TypeError: keywords must be strings
```

I'd like to keep g1 and g2 nodes as integers for downstream indexing, however, the position dictionaries need strings as keys.

I'm keeping nodes separate from labels to ensure I don't get self loops when both graphs have the same node.

Here is the line I insert after setting set_node_attributes to get the correct plot.

```
g1 = relabel_nodes(g1, g1_labels)
g2 = relabel_nodes(g2, g2_labels)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was only a small issue in joining the two dicts. With all the imports:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
import numpy as np

n, p, seedd = 5, 0.7, 13
g1 = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(3, 1, seed=seedd, directed=False)
g2 = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(n, p, seed=seedd, directed=False)

# making sure nodes are not duplicated for drawing edges later.
dup = 0
for i in g1.nodes:
    if g2.has_node(i):
        dup = dup + 1
g2 = nx.relabel_nodes(g2, {i: i + dup for i in g2.nodes})

g1_labels = {i: label for i, label in enumerate(['appel', 'peahc', 'pppuy'])}
g2_labels = {i: label for i, label in zip(g2.nodes, ['ape', 'apple', 'peach', 'puppy', 'rand'])}
nx.set_node_attributes(g1, g1_labels, 'label')
nx.set_node_attributes(g2, g2_labels, 'label')

pos_1 = nx.spring_layout(g1)
pos_2 = nx.spring_layout(g2)

# shift g2 away from g1 for plotting.
for node in g2:
    pos_2[node][0] += 4

# map nodes across g1 and g2 randomly.
g2_map = np.random.choice(g2.nodes, nx.number_of_nodes(g1), replace=False)
new_bipartite = [[i, j] for i, j in zip(g1.nodes, g2_map)]
B = nx.Graph()
B.add_nodes_from(g1.nodes, bipartite=0)
B.add_nodes_from(g2.nodes, bipartite=1)
B.add_edges_from(new_bipartite)

pl.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
nx.draw_networkx(g1, pos_1, node_color='#5499c7', node_size=400, with_labels=False)
nx.draw_networkx(g2, pos_2, node_color='#d35400', node_size=400, with_labels=False)

g1_color = ['#5499c7' for node in range(0, nx.number_of_nodes(g1))]
g2_color = ['#d35400' for node in range(0, nx.number_of_nodes(g2))]


nx.draw_networkx(B, pos={**pos_1, **pos_2}, width=2, style='dashed', node_color=g1_color + g2_color, node_size=400,
                 font_size=28)
```